# Read and Decode base64 XML and save it to PDF in PowerShell

Tags: xml, pdf, xml-parsing, base64, powershell-3.0

I have hundred of XMLs encoded with base64 and results are PDF, is it possible to create a PowerShell script to loop whole folder with XMLs and re-save them as *.bin or PDFs files?

For example this works:

```bsh
$file = "C:\PS\1.xml";
[System.Convert]::FromBase64String((Get-Content $file)) |
    Set-Content "C:\PS\output.bin" -Encoding Byte
```

But how to change "C:\PS\1.xml" to something for loop and convert every single XML file and save them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking is fairly trivial. Use `Get-ChildItem` for enumerating the input files, then process them in a `ForEach-Object` loop where you derive the output filename from the input filename.

```bsh
Get-ChildItem 'C:\PS' -Filter '*.xml' | ForEach-Object {
    $outfile = Join-Path $_.DirectoryName ($_.BaseName + '.pdf')
    # rest of your code goes here
}
```

Use `$_.FullName` instead of `$file` and use `$outfile` instead of the path string.